# Multiple pages at the same time on a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is there a possibility to display two pages at the same time, when using a `ViewPager`? I'm not looking for an edge effect, but rather for two **full** pages at the same time.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking..can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I want to to have the ViewPager display two of the available pages side by side, just like a book.

Comment: could you use two fragments to achieve a pages side by side effect?     its just an idea... dont blame me.....

Answer (score 69):

Please have a look at the `getPageWidth` Method in the corresponding `PagerAdapter`. Override it and return e.g. `0.8f` to have all child pages span only 80% of the ViewPager's width.

More info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth(int)

Comment: the problem with that technique, is that an extra margin-bottom appears, adding weird blank space below the Viewpager

Comment: This adds some flickering effect on view pager, I can still swipe and can see views make weird flickering.

Answer (score 36):

**See my more up-to-date answer here: [Can ViewPager have multiple views in per page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468581/can-viewpager-have-multiple-views-in-per-page/15006910#15006910)**

I discovered that a perhaps even simpler solution through specifying a negative margin for the ViewPager. I've created the MultiViewPager project on GitHub, which you may want to take a look at:

> https://github.com/Pixplicity/MultiViewPager

Although this question specifically asks for a solution without edge effect, some answers here propose the workaround by CommonsWare, such as the suggestion by kaw.

There are various problems with touch handling and hardware acceleration with that particular solution. A simpler and more elegant solution, in my opinion, is to specify a negative margin for the ViewPager:

```
ViewPager.setPageMargin(
    getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.viewpager_margin));
```

I then specified this dimension in my `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="viewpager_margin">-64dp</dimen>
```

To compensate for overlapping pages, each page's content view has the opposite margin:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewpager_margin_fix"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/viewpager_margin_fix"
```

Again in `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="viewpager_margin_fix">32dp</dimen>
```

(Note that the `viewpager_margin_fix` dimension is half that of the absolute `viewpager_margin` dimension.)

We implemented this [in the Dutch newspaper app *De Telegraaf Krant*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trab.news):

[image: Phone example in De Telegraaf Krant][image: Tablet example]

Comment: I loved your solution. Simple and elegant... ! Thanks man. I was trying to achieve this using `PageTransformer`.

Comment: worked for me. You also need to add setOffScreenPageLimit(2) to improve the caching to 2 to avoid lagging on the second next view.

Comment: In previous note: That's ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2) in case anyone gets thrown off.

Answer (score 13):

You have to override the  `getPageWidth()` method on the viewpager's Adapter. For Example:

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return 0.9f;
}
```

Try that code in your Adapter and then you'll understand.

Comment: This looks very similar to @Markus-Wörz answer?

Answer (score 5):

See [that blog entry](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html).
PagerContainer technique is solved my problem.

**EDIT:**
I found same answer.
[How to migrate from Gallery to HorizontalScrollView & ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240387/1070696)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you like to add an excerpt of that blog post to your answer, so that it will still be useful if the link dies?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thank you for your advice. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by using getPageWidth in PagerAdapter class.

***Be sure about whether your JAR is up-to-date***.Since previously ViewPager was not supporting multiple pages at the same time.

public float getPageWidth(){

return 0.4f;(You can choose it .For full screen per page you should give 1f)
}

Answer (score 3):

create your layout file: my_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/pager_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

the viewpager is about as small as you want your pages to be. With android:clipToPadding="false" the pages outside the pager are visible as well. But now dragging outside the viewpager has no effect This can be remedied by picking touches from the pager-container and passing them on to the pager:

```
MyLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.<MyLayoutBinding>inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.my_layout, parent, false)
binding.pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
binding.pager.setPageMargin(15);
binding.pagerContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           return chatCollectionLayoutBinding.pager.onTouchEvent(event);
      }
 });
```

Comment: What is MyLayoutBinding can you show me full example

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that's possible with the limitations of a View Pager. It only allows a user to view pages 1 at a time. You might be able to work something out with the use of fragments, and have 2 ViewPager fragments side by side and use buttons to work out the page flipping you want to implement, but the code may become very complex.

You can try something like a ViewFlipper - where you can do a lot more customizations (including animations).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

It can be don in the **Item Layout** of the Viewpager. Assume that, you want two pages at a time.

This is the **Item Layout** (photo_slider_item.xml):

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/photosSliderItem">
        <ImageView android:id="@id/photoBox1" style="@style/photoBox"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@id/photoBox2" style="@style/photoBox"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And in your PagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
    View sliderItem = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(photo_slider_item, container, false);
    ImageView photoBox1 = (ImageView) sliderItem.findViewById(R.id.photoBox1);
    ImageView photoBox2 = (ImageView) sliderItem.findViewById(R.id.photoBox2);
    photoBox1.setImageResource(photosIds[position]);
    if(position < photosIds.length-1){
        photoBox2.setImageResource(photosIds[position+1]);
    } else {photoBox2.setImageResource(photosIds[0]);}
    container.addView(sliderItem);
    return sliderItem;
}
```

**Edited version for more than two items**

if you want more than two items, first add your items to the **LinearLayout** then use following algorithm:

```
photoBox1.setImageResource(photosIds[position]);
if(position < photosIds.length-i-1){
   photoBox2.setImageResource(photosIds[position+1]);
   photoBox3.setImageResource(photosIds[position+2]);
   .
   .
   .
   photoBox(i).setImageResource(photosIds[position+i-1]);
} else if(position < photosIds.length-i-2){
   photoBox2.setImageResource(photosIds[position+1]);
   photoBox3.setImageResource(photosIds[position+2]);
   .
   .
   .
   photoBox(i-1).setImageResource(photosIds[position+i-2]);
   photoBox(i).setImageResource(photosIds[0]);
} . . . else if(position < photosIds.length-1){
   photoBox2.setImageResource(photosIds[position+1]);
   photoBox3.setImageResource(photosIds[0]);
   photoBox4.setImageResource(photosIds[1]);
   .
   .
   .
   photoBox(i-1).setImageResource(photosIds[i-2-2]);
   photoBox(i).setImageResource(photosIds[i-2-1]);
} else {
    photoBox2.setImageResource(photosIds[0]);
    photoBox3.setImageResource(photosIds[1]);
    .
    .
    .
    photoBox(i-1).setImageResource(photosIds[i-1-2]);
    photoBox(i).setImageResource(photosIds[i-1-1]);
}
```

**i**       : number of your items

**[i-2-2]** : number 2 in the middle is number of items in the last page of the **viewpager**.

Comment: how to make it three per page