# How to migrate from Gallery to HorizontalScrollView & ViewPager?

Tags: android, gallery, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview, migrate

I need simple control for icon choosing on Android 2.2 and higher.
Gallery was a better solution for me, but it is deprecated and I have to use `HorizontalScrollView` and `ViewPager` instead.
But how to migrate easy? How to use this classes and controls in this case? I've try to find complete example for this subject, but I can't find it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086991/display-of-multiple-pages-in-viewpager-incorrect-position

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[This gist from Dave Smith](https://gist.github.com/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1) shows a way to use `ViewPager` to have visual results very similar to a `Gallery`:

[image: Gallery-style ViewPager]

Quoting [my blog post on the topic](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html) of showing multiple pages at a time in a `ViewPager`:

> His container (`com.example.pagercontainer.PagerContainer`) wraps the `ViewPager` and calls `setClipChildren(false);` on itself, so even though the `ViewPager` is focused on one selected page, other pages that have coordinates beyond the `ViewPager` bounds are still visible, so long as they fit within the `PagerContainer`. By sizing the `ViewPager` to be smaller than the `PagerContainer`, the `ViewPager` can size its pages to that size, leaving room for other pages to be seen. `PagerContainer`, though, needs to help out a bit with touch events, as `ViewPager` will only handle swipe events on its own visible bounds, ignoring any pages visible to the sides.

You might also want to sift through [this android-developers thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/RIERxUcGpQg), where somebody pointed out an issue with this on newer Android versions. You need to disable hardware acceleration [due to a bug in `ViewPager`](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36788).

Comment: Thank you for answer! But this example from Dave Smith require API version 11, and I need 8...

Comment: @BArtWell: What makes you say that it requires API Level 11? `ViewPager` works back to API Level 4 AFAIK.

Comment: "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.widget.FrameLayout#setLayerType" in
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: @BArtWell: You do not need to call that on older versions of Android. Simply call that only on API Level 11, by checking the version using `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.

Comment: yes, it help, thank's! Now I see that Dave Smith's solution is works, but it show only one picture at the moment (Gallery was show 3 and central is selected).
P.S. Why Gallery is deprecated? :( It was so easy and so handy...

Comment: @BArtWell: That is the bug -- if you disable hardware acceleration as described in the android-developers thread, it works.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank's. May be I can stay on Gallery? It is so easy-to-use... Or this is totally inadmissible?

Comment: @BArtWell: "Deprecated" in Android means "this is no longer recommended, but we will continue to support it as long as possible". If you want to go with `Gallery` for the short term, that's fine, but I would look to try to do something else within, say, a year. Since `ViewPager` is in the Android Support package, the hardware acceleration related bug could be fixed in the next few months.

Comment: @CommonsWare:I am displaying three view in a screen.How to get positions of left and right view when click on a view. I am always getting right side view position even i clock on left side view

Comment: hi. i tried the PagerContainer and all the hints about hardware acceleration, but i don't get it working. neither on nexus 7, 4 or emulator. i can only see the center image, but not prev/next. i use a custom ViewPager witch measures childs heigths and a relative layout with two imageviews inside. maybe someone have more suggestions ?

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare. I've got a couple of questions. 1) Does this solution includes any recycling mechanism? 2) How do handle **selection events**? Does it consider **selection events** at all?

Comment: @Axel: "Does this solution includes any recycling mechanism?" -- no. "How do handle selection events? Does it consider selection events at all?" -- being the current page in the `ViewPager` would correspond to being selected in a `Gallery`.

Comment: I see. @CommonsWare please do you think you could take a quick look at this question http://goo.gl/Z9UzQv ? It's related to this one. I know you're a busy man, but just a comment or perhaps some hints you could give me, I'm sure they would point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are various problems with touch handling and hardware acceleration in CommonsWare's linked workaround. A simpler and more elegant solution, in my opinion, is to specify a negative margin for the ViewPager:

```
ViewPager.setPageMargin(
    getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.viewpager_margin));
```

I then specified this dimension in my `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="viewpager_margin">-64dp</dimen>
```

To compensate for overlapping pages, each page's content view has the opposite margin:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/viewpager_margin_fix"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/viewpager_margin_fix"
```

Again in `dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="viewpager_margin_fix">32dp</dimen>
```

(Note that the `viewpager_margin_fix` dimension is half that of the absolute `viewpager_margin` dimension.)

We implemented this [in the Dutch newspaper app *De Telegraaf Krant*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trab.news):

[image: Phone example in De Telegraaf Krant][image: Tablet example]

Comment: Your approach seems pretty nice, can you show the whole source code? I can't see if you handle the first element with a specific treatment. I can't reproduce the behaviour entirely. Thanks for share anyway!

Comment: Yes, the primary problem with this approach is that you have to specify the overlap as a dimension manually. This doesn't scale well for different device classes, so in my own implementations I've subclassed ViewPager to compute it dynamically in `onLayout()`. I've frequently been asked to open source it; I will when I have a moment to spare. In the meantime, see also the remarks on [my answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468581/can-viewpager-have-multiple-views-in-per-page/15006910#15006910).

Comment: I appreciate the redirect. I'll see if I can make work it out.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I need to work more on it but looks like it's the path.