# How to stop backward animation of a gallery view

Tags: android, android-animation

I used gallery view to display images but I want only one side to scroll. How do I stop left to right scrolling or backward scrolling? Or how do I create custom gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GallerView is a deprecated widget.

I use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) which you can modify as a custom gallery. Your fragments will be your slides or images which you will be able to swipe around.

You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239886/how-to-migrate-from-gallery-to-horizontalscrollview-viewpager).

If you want to swipe only one way, then you would have to extend ViewPager and override onTouch event.

Comment: i used that but i have to display 3 images at time center, previous and next. the previous and next image show little not whole. but in viewpager when i swipe next image it swipe whole page with 3 images.

Comment: That's not the case. With ViewPager you can specify any sizes. Have a look at the second link I gave you. There is an image where 3 pictures are seen at the same time.

Comment: Otherwise (I haven't tried that, but..) you could extend GalleryView and override its onTouchEvent.

Comment: Thanks this work for me but i want show images in circular way after last image display first again and so on , and another one is how to stop left to right scrolling in pagecontainer.

Comment: Then you will have to create a new question as your original question does not specify that.