# Page indicator in android

Tags: android

I have done `Gallery View`

```
gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    gallery.setAdapter(adapter);
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent go = new Intent(Department2.this,
                    tablistclass_item.class);
            if (!larg) {

                go = new Intent(Department2.this, ListClass.class);
            }

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("headername", nameofimage[position]);
            b.putString("whichclass", "department");
            go.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(go);
        }
    });
}
```

Now how to make `page indicator` for `Gallery view`

Comment: please refer https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing an indicator using a Gallery is difficult since you have no reliable way of knowing the index of the item that is currently at the center. Gallery has also been [deprecated since API 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239886/how-to-migrate-from-gallery-to-horizontalscrollview-viewpager).

Instead you can use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). It is available through the [Android support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for older versions of Android as well.

You can use [Jake Wharton's ViewPager Indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) in conjunction with this to get many kinds of indicators for your ViewPager or you can just have a look at the source code and construct your own.

Answer (score 0):

Just add images according to your page position Like make a active image and other inactive images based on your page position. You can add the images dynamically.