# Android: Horizontal Image Gridview/Scroll?

Tags: java, android, image, gridview, horizontal-scrolling

Have any of you tried out any Horizontal Scrolls/Gridviews to display Images similar to the Facebook mobile image viewer that allows the user to scroll images horizontal one after the other. The android gallery is another example.

I tried to implement this using [THIS](https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/horizontal-scrolling-pages/) tutorial but I didn't get the desired output. Any other codes and layouts you guys have tried?

EDITED:
What I basically want is to implement a horizontal scrolling of images as seen on [THIS](http://ak1.polyvoreimg.com/cgi/img-set/cid/121650774/id/tOf8HXLY4xG-WIrhBhFvvQ/size/y.jpg) image. As you can see the gridview displays image one after the other. That tutorial caused some errors therefore I didn't continue with it.

I tried the following layout

**XML Layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/pager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0px"
 android:layout_weight="1">
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: May be useful to describe "desired output". What, specifically, was lacking with it?

Comment: Add some code what you have tried... else I am sure your question will be downvoted and closed

Comment: just check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656949/how-to-implement-horizontalscrollview-like-gallery...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that with Viewpager:

- [Multiple pages at the same time on a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836323/multiple-pages-at-the-same-time-on-a-viewpager)

As for horizontal scroll in GridView here're some links:

- https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5537327
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919257