# How is playstore app displaying multiples pages on view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have tried this [Multiple pages at the same time on a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836323/multiple-pages-at-the-same-time-on-a-viewpager), I couldn't  customize it same as google play app.

My questions are.
1. Is it actually a viewpager used in google play store app? 
2. How to get this done?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: its a different recylerview or list view put vertically or scroll horizontal not view pager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a `ViewPager`, it is a `RecyclerView` which has `Horizontal` LinearLayout Manager and also have `LinearSnapHelper`

You can use snapHelper like this:

```
SnapHelper snapHelper;

snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

LayoutManager:

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its a view pager with two tabs in which the swipe is disabled and the one you marked is a horizontal recycler view.

//CustomViewPager Class

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    return super.executeKeyEvent(event);
}
```

}

//layout

```
    <com.dolevel.level.utils.CustomViewPager
    android:layout_below="@id/progress_bar"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/stepper_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Please do not mislead people. OP is asking the RecyclerView part.

Comment: I did. Nothing changed. OP asks if it's a ViewPager and how its done. Just check my answer.

Comment: Cool cool .Honestly speaking It's a `Horizontal RecyclerView`