# How to achieve image slider like the one in the playstore homepage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a marketplace app that has this feature. I believe that this feature uses ViewPager but I am unsure on how to implement such features. Any help will be appreciated.

[How to acheive this effect?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sE8P.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is playstore app displaying multiples pages on view pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699046/how-is-playstore-app-displaying-multiples-pages-on-view-pager)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Best Solution I have Seen.
I have Already Used this for Many of my apps.

Must optimize it for the new versions of build/apis

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this, RecyclerView with Horizontal Scroll

```
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManagerNewlyAded = new LinearLayoutManager(SingletonApp.getInstance().getActivityInstance(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerViewNewlyAdded.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManagerNewlyAded);
```

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal recycler view in playstore uses a `linear snap helper` from the support library  or something similar

```
    LinearSnapHelper linearSnapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    linearSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```